# Perform sum on count from subquery in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to perform sum on all orders received from the sub-query count of orders, but i am getting an error saying **Error Code: 1242. Sub-query returns more than 1 row**

Query:

```
select sum((select count(orderNo) as count from  order r group by r.status 
having r.status in ('Open','shipped In Progress','New')));
```

Comment: it is equivalent to `select count(r.orderNo) from order r where status in ...`, no?

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong,he is trying to sum the count of rows from the sub-query,

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `GROUP BY` and use `WHERE`

```
select sum(  (select count(orderNo) as count 
              from  order r 
              WHERE r.status in ('Open','shipped In Progress','New')
             )
          );
```

Actually you don't need `SUM` or sub query:

```
SELECT count(orderNo) as count 
FROM   order r 
WHERE r.status in ('Open','shipped In Progress','New')
```

Comment: Great answer. It notes the fact that a subquery is not needed but also answers OP's question as stated (assuming OP might be using aggregates in the real query). I'd accept it. :D

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out a way which works for me.

```
select sum(a.count) 
from(select count(o.order) as count from order o )a
```

Comment: So what about my answer? Suddenly you dont need check status?  Because as I said you dont need a subquery for that.